# Guidelines for Answer Deletion

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

In addition to closing poor questions, the issue of deletion of extremely poor answers has been raised, so I'm posting to solicit a conversation on guidelines for deleting answers.

**1. Off-topic answers**

This refers to answers that do not address the question.  (Exceptions would be answers that present relevant, corollary information that broadens understanding of the topic.)

**2. Disinformation**

Unlike [misinformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misinformation), which arises from genuine lack of understanding, [disinformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disinformation) is intentional and malicious. (The remedy for misinformation is downvoting; for disinformation the remedy is deletion.)

**3. Spam**

Using an answer to promote a product.  Also includes links to web resources not related to the subject of the question, or a relevant corollary subject.

**4. Code of conduct violations**

Goes without saying.  Includes answers that are inflammatory, rude, contain profanity, or which target individuals who are not public figures.

---

**Bans**

Violations of the code of conduct will also likely result in bans, as the activity is clear cut.

For off-topic, disinformation & spam, which may be less clear in some cases, repeated instances can be grounds for a ban.

---

*Let me know if I've missed anything, and any other thoughts on these guidelines.*

Answer (score 2):

In general, I agree with these guidelines. However, I think that misinformation can also be a good reason for deleting an answer, because (intentionally or not) the answer can be harmful. Moreover, it is not always clear the intentions of the answerer. If a user regularly gives answers with misleading or wrong information, this is an obvious sign that his/her answers need to be deleted and this user can and probably should be banned.